# Get Json details depending upon the name selected in previous page (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, url-routing

I have a problem of getting the json data depending on the value selected on other HTML page with different controller serving different page

My home page consist of table which is looping through json data

```
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Time</th>       
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat = 'row in rows'>
          <td><a href="#about/{{row.name}}">{{row.name}}</a></td>
          <td>{{ row.phone}}</td>
          <td>{{row.time}} </td>    
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and depending upon the name selected from table, it is routed to different page showing name of selected persons name through `$routeParams`, But i also want to get other details that person from that json

http://plnkr.co/edit/iha3M0KThZegme8yKRz9?p=preview

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to get that data in the second page somehow. You have a couple of options listed in my order of preference

1. Make a service that makes the http call then caches the Json and inject that into both controllers.
2. Make the controller that holds the entire JSON control both the different type of pages.
3. Make another http call in the other controller so you have access to the json.

Comment: Thanks ..Can you help me in getting data of matching person with option 3

Answer (score 0):

A service is what you are looking for.  Here's your code reflecting the addition of a service:

```
    // create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  // route for the about page
  .when('/about/:person', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
  })

});

scotchApp.service('dataService', function($http) {

  var dataService = {
    getData: function() {
      return $http.get("call_queue.json");
    }
  };

  return dataService;
});


// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, dataService) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'contacts';
  dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.rows = response.data
  });
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $routeParams, dataService) {
  $scope.message = 'Clicked person name from home page is dispalyed here, but wanted other datails also';
  $scope.person = $routeParams.person;
  dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
    $scope.rows = response.data
  });
});
```

You can decide if you want to make the $http.get() call each time your service is accessed or you can make the call once and cache the data in the service in a variable that you expose.

Comment: how to loop through and get the data of the matched person

Comment: Change your aboutController to iterate through the results from the call to the service..  Like this:    
      dataService.getData().then(function(response) {
        angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
          if (key === enteredValue) {
            $scope.results.push({
              serial: key,
              owner: value[0].Owner
            });
          }